# Data is not Found from Database in PHP

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

Today or Current Date Birthday Date Retrieve From the Ms Access Database.Suppose Today Date is 03-08-2018. I passed value only Date and Month day = 03, Month = 08 and year is not Pass. So, I Retrieve Current day and month record.

Data Retrieve Query in `PHP` File.This Query Run in Ms Access database is Successfully and fetch current date Record but In `PHP` file Give Empty Data.

Passed data in `url` just Like this: `localhost/Bi.php?Chhaprabhatha&mon=8&day=3`

Its Give Result Like This: `Resource id #4{"status":0,"0":[]}`

Query is Run in Database its give Result and Successfully run.In this code give null data

Bi.php

```
  <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST["Chhaprabhatha"])) 
        { 

        include 'Connection.php';


        $mon = $_GET['mon'];
        $day = $_GET['day'];

        $sql = "select std_name, regno,standard,division
        FROM(select RegNo,b.Standard,c.Division,std_name,DOB as BirthDayDate,contactno1 as contact, Year(DOB) AS OrderYear,  month(DOB) AS OrderMonth,Day(DOB) AS OrderDay,a.YearID,IsActive
         from ((std_reg as a inner join standardmaster as b on a.standard = b.stdid)
        inner join divisionmaster as c on a.division = c.divisionid)
        ) as t where (t.OrderMonth = $mon AND t.OrderDay = $day  and t.Isactive = true)";


        echo $stmt = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

        $result = [];
        do {
            while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){
               $result[] = $row; 
            }
        } while (odbc_next_result($stmt));

        if(count($result)>0)
        {
            $result1['status']=1;//"Login successfully";
            echo array_push($result1,$result);
        }
        else
        {
             //$result[]="null";
            $result1['status']=0;//"Record not found";
            array_push($result1,$result);
        }
        odbc_free_result($stmt);
        odbc_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

        echo json_encode($result1); //You will get the encoded array variable

        }
?>
```

Comment: show input values

Comment: http://localhost/Birthday.php?Chhaprabhatha&mon=8&day=1

Comment: What are the types of *$_GET* variables? No links please.

Comment: Get value from The Url And Passed in Query.

Comment: Once again -what are the types? String? Number? Please run `gettype($mon)` and `gettype($day)`. Please note in English, not all words are capitalized in sentences: only the beginning of sentence and proper nouns. Please edit your grammar.